# Variar datos de scrollTop según el ancho de la ventana

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

El código que muestro a continuación está perfecto. Lo único que me gustaría que cuando el ancho de la ventana sea inferior a **450px** el Top varíe de "- 43" a "0".

```
$(".edgtf-btn.edgtf-btn-solid").click(function () {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($("#portfolio-lista").offset().top - 43) + 'px'
    }, 600, 'easeOutQuad');
});
```

Comment: Puedes utilizar [innerWidth y innerHeight](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp) junto con [window.resize](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp) para saber el momento en que el ancho cambia y puedas modificar el estilo.

Comment: Gracias Vick Muñoz, si me lo desarrollas te lo agradecería. A lo mejor no es muy complejo, pero mis conocimientos son bastante básicos.